# Нарезка видео по сценам

Tags: ffmpeg

Подскажите, как видео автоматически нарезать на части, где каждая часть, это отдельный видео файлик со сценой?
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RTbO5sXmr98 вот например такую колбасу порезать по сценам, чтобы из 1 видео файла, состоящего из 10 роликов, получилось 10 видео файлов, где 1 файл = видео ролик. спасибо

Возможно ли это сделать с ffmpeg?

Answer (score 1):

Без каких-либо однотипных разделителей между блоками, автоматическое разделение весьма сомнительно.

Даже если бы они были, мне не известно программ, способных находить похожие участки в видеофайле, хотя, реализовать такое, очевидно, возможно.

Comment: Дополню (можешь в ответ добавить, не жалко :)): 
@ralfibb, писать свою программу используя библиотеки ffmpeg (libavformat, libavcodec & etc) и opencv, реализовав алгоритм нахождения похожести смежных кадров. В принципе, можно и без opencv - реализовав какой-нить просто алгоритм сравнения двух кадров вручную, рекомендации или простую формулу можно посмотреть тут: https://toster.ru/q/21214. А можешь мне заказать ;-)